# How to increase Valgrind's report output limitation?

Tags: valgrind

I'm currently using valgrind for memcheck using this command :

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --log-file=valg.log myprog
```

but i don't get ever the full report i remarked that output buffer is always stuck at the same size (54 ko or 617 line for me). Is there a way to increase this limitation or to force the generation of the summary report (HEAP SUMMARY and LEAK SUMMARY)?

here you can see the end part of the log.

```
==62==    at 0x531CDDC: memcpy (vg_replace_strmem.c:10)
==62==    by 0x50EDA03: je_malloc_tsd_boot0 (in /system/lib64/libc.so)
==62==    by 0x50E39E3: jemalloc_constructor (in /system/lib64/libc.so)
==62==    by 0x402C473: __dl__ZL10call_arrayIPFviPPcS1_EEvPKcPT_mbS5_ (in /system/bin/linker64)
==62==    by 0x402C68F: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==62==    by 0x402C597: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==62==    by 0x402C597: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==62==    by 0x402C597: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==62==    by 0x402C597: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==62==    by 0x402C597: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==62==    by 0x402C597: __dl__ZN6soinfo17call_constructorsEv (in /system/bin/linker64)
==62==    by 0x40286CF: __dl___linker_init (in /system/bin/linker64)
```

Comment: Can you post a bit more before the memcpy line that you posted (just a few lines) so that we can tell what the callstack is for? It could be a Valgrind crash or a guest application error. If it is a guest crash then Valgrind will do its best to continue amd exit gracefully but it can't always do that.

Comment: @PaulFloyd, no its not neither a valgrind crach or a guest application it's just an other error report. I tried to kill the valgrind process but no summary report generation just the valgrind restarted again and generate new log.

Comment: @PaulFloyd it's like valgrind didn't get notified to stop memcheck and generate summary by using kill command, is there a way to notify valgrind to finish his job ?

Comment: If you just use 'kill' then you should get a report. If you use 'kill -9' then you won't. It's also possible that your application is doing an 'exec'. In that case, if you aren't using `--trace-children=yes` then the child will execute standalone and replace the valgrind process. In that case you will also get no summary after the 'exec'.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I used --trace-children=yes and the default kill but same result, an other remark that i cannot find the pid that is mentioned on the log (62 on that case) when i execute the command "ps -ef" instead of that i found valgrind running with other pid and when i kill it, it generates new report without the summary part.

Comment: There is only one process - whatever valgrind tool you are using. The guest application "runs" as a virtual process within the valgrind process.

Comment: @PaulFloyd you cannot suggest any solutions to me because i had read the user manual and am stuck on it without finding solution. is there a method to check log to see if valgrind exit successfully or not or any other ideas

Comment: Valgrind itself has a many tracing options. -v, -d (both may be repeated to increase verbosity). Then you could try syscall tracing tools like dtrace, ktrace and strace. Finally you could run Valgrind under gdb - see the readme file for developers if you want to try that.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I forced valgrind's code to generate the report at the exit but i don't know if it affect the functionality of the tool and it's credibility or not ==> on the function `run_a_thread_NORETURN`on syswrap-linux.c file. Please if you know the code could you tell me if it's ok or it will damage the report ?